# Strikes only counting next ball instead of next two balls in Bowling Scorer?

Tags: java

Apologies for the extremely long and inefficient programming, I've taken it upon myself to make it as long as possible :p I've tested the scorer, and everything but strikes function properly. But for some reason, A strike only adds the next ball instead of the next two balls. thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class bowlingproject {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] bowlingArray = new int[2][11];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int score1;
    int score2;
    int score3;
    int score4;
    int score5;
    int score6;
    int score7;
    int score8;
    int score9;
    int score10;
    int allscore;

    System.out.println("Frame 1: first ball");
    bowlingArray[0][0] = in.nextInt();
    if (bowlingArray[0][0] == 10) {
        bowlingArray[1][0] = 0;
        System.out.println("Strike!");
    } else if (bowlingArray[0][0] != 10) {
        System.out.println("Frame 1: second ball");
        bowlingArray[1][0] = in.nextInt();
        if (bowlingArray[0][0] + bowlingArray[1][0] == 10) {
            System.out.println("Spare!");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Frame 2: first ball");
    bowlingArray[0][1] = in.nextInt();
    if (bowlingArray[0][1] == 10) {
        bowlingArray[1][1] = 0;
        System.out.println("Strike!");
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][1] != 10) {
        System.out.println("Frame 2: second ball");
        bowlingArray[1][1] = in.nextInt();
        if (bowlingArray[0][1] + bowlingArray[1][1] == 10) {
            System.out.println("Spare!");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Frame 3: first ball");
    bowlingArray[0][2] = in.nextInt();
    if (bowlingArray[0][2] == 10) {
        bowlingArray[1][2] = 0;
        System.out.println("Strike!");
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][2] != 10) {
        System.out.println("Frame 3: second ball");
        bowlingArray[1][2] = in.nextInt();
        if (bowlingArray[0][2] + bowlingArray[1][2] == 10) {
            System.out.println("Spare!");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Frame 4: first ball");
    bowlingArray[0][3] = in.nextInt();
    if (bowlingArray[0][3] == 10) {
        bowlingArray[1][3] = 0;
        System.out.println("Strike!");
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][3] != 10) {
        System.out.println("Frame 4: second ball");
        bowlingArray[1][3] = in.nextInt();
        if (bowlingArray[0][3] + bowlingArray[1][3] == 10) {
            System.out.println("Spare!");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Frame 5: first ball");
    bowlingArray[0][4] = in.nextInt();
    if (bowlingArray[0][4] == 10) {
        bowlingArray[1][4] = 0;
        System.out.println("Strike!");
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][4] != 10) {
        System.out.println("Frame 5: second ball");
        bowlingArray[1][4] = in.nextInt();
        if (bowlingArray[0][4] + bowlingArray[1][4] == 10) {
            System.out.println("Spare!");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Frame 6: first ball");
    bowlingArray[0][5] = in.nextInt();
    if (bowlingArray[0][5] == 10) {
        bowlingArray[1][5] = 0;
        System.out.println("Strike!");
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][5] != 10) {
        System.out.println("Frame 6: second ball");
        bowlingArray[1][5] = in.nextInt();
        if (bowlingArray[0][5] + bowlingArray[1][5] == 10) {
            System.out.println("Spare!");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Frame 7: first ball");
    bowlingArray[0][6] = in.nextInt();
    if (bowlingArray[0][6] == 10) {
        bowlingArray[1][6] = 0;
        System.out.println("Strike!");
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][6] != 10) {
        System.out.println("Frame 7: second ball");
        bowlingArray[1][6] = in.nextInt();
        if (bowlingArray[0][6] + bowlingArray[1][6] == 10) {
            System.out.println("Spare!");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Frame 8: first ball");
    bowlingArray[0][7] = in.nextInt();
    if (bowlingArray[0][7] == 10) {
        bowlingArray[1][7] = 0;
        System.out.println("Strike!");
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][7] != 10) {
        System.out.println("Frame 8: second ball");
        bowlingArray[1][7] = in.nextInt();
        if (bowlingArray[0][7] + bowlingArray[1][7] == 10) {
            System.out.println("Spare!");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Frame 9: first ball");
    bowlingArray[0][8] = in.nextInt();
    if (bowlingArray[0][8] == 10) {
        bowlingArray[1][8] = 0;
        System.out.println("Strike!");
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][8] != 10) {
        System.out.println("Frame 9: second ball");
        bowlingArray[1][8] = in.nextInt();
        if (bowlingArray[0][8] + bowlingArray[1][8] == 10) {
            System.out.println("Spare!");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Frame 10: first ball");
    bowlingArray[0][9] = in.nextInt();
    if (bowlingArray[0][9] == 10) {
        System.out.println("Strike!");
        System.out.println("Frame 11: first ball");
        bowlingArray[1][9] = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Frame 11: second ball!");
        bowlingArray[0][10] = in.nextInt();
    } else if (bowlingArray[0][9] != 10) {
        System.out.println("Frame 10: second ball");
        bowlingArray[1][9] = in.nextInt();
        if (bowlingArray[0][9] + bowlingArray[1][9] == 10) {
            System.out.println("Spare!");
            System.out.println("Frame 11: first ball!");
            bowlingArray[0][10] = in.nextInt();
        }
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][0] + bowlingArray[0][1] == 20) {
        score1 = bowlingArray[0][0] + bowlingArray[0][1] + bowlingArray[0][2];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][0] == 10) {
        score1 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][1] + bowlingArray[1][1];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][0] + bowlingArray[1][0] == 10) {
        score1 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][1];
    } else
        score1 = bowlingArray[0][0] + bowlingArray[1][0];

    if (bowlingArray[0][1] + bowlingArray[0][2] == 20) {
        score2 = bowlingArray[0][1] + bowlingArray[0][2] + bowlingArray[0][3];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][1] == 10) {
        score2 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][2] + bowlingArray[1][2];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][1] + bowlingArray[1][1] == 10) {
        score2 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][2];
    } else
        score2 = bowlingArray[0][1] + bowlingArray[1][1];

    if (bowlingArray[0][2] + bowlingArray[0][3] == 20) {
        score3 = bowlingArray[0][2] + bowlingArray[0][3] + bowlingArray[0][4];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][2] == 10) {
        score3 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][3] + bowlingArray[1][3];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][2] + bowlingArray[1][2] == 10) {
        score3 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][3];
    } else
        score3 = bowlingArray[0][2] + bowlingArray[1][2];

    if (bowlingArray[0][3] + bowlingArray[0][4] == 20) {
        score4 = bowlingArray[0][3] + bowlingArray[0][4] + bowlingArray[0][5];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][3] == 10) {
        score4 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][4] + bowlingArray[1][4];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][3] + bowlingArray[1][3] == 10) {
        score4 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][4];
    } else
        score4 = bowlingArray[0][3] + bowlingArray[1][3];

    if (bowlingArray[0][4] + bowlingArray[0][5] == 20) {
        score5 = bowlingArray[0][4] + bowlingArray[0][5] + bowlingArray[0][6];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][4] == 10) {
        score5 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][5] + bowlingArray[1][5];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][4] + bowlingArray[1][4] == 10) {
        score5 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][5];
    } else
        score5 = bowlingArray[0][4] + bowlingArray[1][4];

    if (bowlingArray[0][5] + bowlingArray[0][6] == 20) {
        score6 = bowlingArray[0][5] + bowlingArray[0][6] + bowlingArray[0][7];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][5] == 10) {
        score6 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][6] + bowlingArray[1][6];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][5] + bowlingArray[1][5] == 10) {
        score6 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][6];
    } else
        score6 = bowlingArray[0][5] + bowlingArray[1][5];

    if (bowlingArray[0][6] + bowlingArray[0][7] == 20) {
        score7 = bowlingArray[0][6] + bowlingArray[0][7] + bowlingArray[0][8];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][6] == 10) {
        score7 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][7] + bowlingArray[1][7];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][6] + bowlingArray[1][6] == 10) {
        score7 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][7];
    } else
        score7 = bowlingArray[0][6] + bowlingArray[1][6];

    if (bowlingArray[0][7] + bowlingArray[0][8] == 20) {
        score8 = bowlingArray[0][7] + bowlingArray[0][8] + bowlingArray[0][9];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][7] == 10) {
        score8 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][8] + bowlingArray[1][8];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][7] + bowlingArray[1][7] == 10) {
        score8 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][8];
    } else
        score8 = bowlingArray[0][7] + bowlingArray[1][7];

    if (bowlingArray[0][8] + bowlingArray[0][9] == 20) {
        score9 = bowlingArray[0][8] + bowlingArray[0][9] + bowlingArray[0][10];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][8] == 10) {
        score9 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][9] + bowlingArray[1][9];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][8] + bowlingArray[1][8] == 10) {
        score9 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][9];
    } else
        score9 = bowlingArray[0][8] + bowlingArray[1][8];

    if (bowlingArray[0][9] == 10) {
        score10 = 10 + bowlingArray[1][9] + bowlingArray[0][10];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][9] + bowlingArray[1][9] == 10) {
        score10 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][10];
    } else
        score10 = bowlingArray[0][9] + bowlingArray[1][9];

    allscore = score1 + score2 + score3 + score4 + score5 + score6 + score7 + score8 + score9 + score10;

    System.out.println("Your score is:" + allscore);

}
```

}

Comment: Could you narrow the problem down, because yes it is rather long to skim through lines of code which may be irrelevant

Comment: after brief testing, it seems that the scorer for strikes is not working properly. so the bottom half of the code (starting from " if (bowlingArray[0][0] + bowlingArray[0][1] == 20) {" doesnt function when strikes are involved.

Comment: the first two if statements  involving each score variable (score1, score2, score3, etc) are for counting strikes. so if (bowlingArray[][] + bowlingArray[][] == 20) { is for strikes when the ball you roll after a strike is also a strike. the second if statement is for when you get a strike, but the next number is not a strike. for some reason, for both statements it only adds 1 ball to the strike and not 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you set the second ball to 0 when you got a Strike:

```
if (bowlingArray[0][0] == 10) {
    bowlingArray[1][0] = 0;
    System.out.println("Strike!");
```

and later:

```
    if (bowlingArray[0][0] == 10) {
        score1 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][1] + bowlingArray[1][1];
    }
    if (bowlingArray[0][0] + bowlingArray[1][0] == 10) {
        score1 = 10 + bowlingArray[0][1];
    } else
        score1 = bowlingArray[0][0] + bowlingArray[1][0];
```

What happens:
In case of the Strike both ifs will always be true, because it would always be 10+0. the first one saves both values in score1 but gets overwritten by the second if. Possible solution could be using `else if` in the second if statement.